# Postgresql select the two top towns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have row like:

```
user | town 1 | town 2 | town 3 | town 4 | town 5 | town 6|
```

The towns all have integer values where town 3 and town 4 have the largest number

I want to select the two top towns for the user so the end result should be:

```
user | town 3 | town 4 |
```

Comment: With a properly normalized model this would be easy. Why do you store this information in multiple columns? Why don't you put that into a proper 1:many relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the properly normalized model:

```
create table users (
    user_id serial primary key,
    user_name varchar(100)
);

create table town (
    town_id serial primary key,
    town_int int
);

create table user_town (
    town_id int references town (town_id),
    user_id int references users (user_id),
    primary key (user_id, town_id)
);

insert into users (user_name) values ('John');
insert into town (town_int) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
insert into user_town (user_id, town_id) values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6);
```

How to query it:

```
select user_id, user_name, town_id, town_int
from
    user_town
    inner join
    users using (user_id)
    inner join
    town using (town_id)
where user_id = 1
order by town_int desc
limit 2
;
 user_id | user_name | town_id | town_int 
---------+-----------+---------+----------
       1 | John      |       6 |        6
       1 | John      |       5 |        5
```

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes we have just what we have, poor designed legacy DB for example. Then

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 100 as userid, 11 as town1, 23 as town2, 77 as town3, 14 as town4, 15 as town5, 16 as town6
UNION ALL
SELECT 101 as userid, 21 as town1, 235 as town2, 177 as town3, 24 as town4, 25 as town5, 26 as town6
) 
SELECT userid, max(r.town) as top1, min(r.town) as top2
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT town1 as town FROM t t2 WHERE t2.userid=t.userid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT town2 FROM t t2 WHERE  t2.userid=t.userid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT town3 FROM t t2 WHERE  t2.userid=t.userid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT town4 FROM t t2 WHERE  t2.userid=t.userid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT town5 FROM t t2 WHERE  t2.userid=t.userid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT town6 FROM t t2 WHERE  t2.userid=t.userid
    ORDER BY town DESC LIMIT 2) AS r
 GROUP BY userid;
```